# Lua script and redis - how to test for None value

Tags: lua, redis

Below is my lua script:

```
     local ckid = redis.pcall('get',KEYS[1])
     local meta = redis.call('hgetall', ckid)
     return {ckid, meta}
```

if the key does not exits for the first call I would not like to execute the second.

So...I don't what the return value is for None.  In python the return value would be None.

```
if ckid ~= '???????' then 
    local meta = redis.call('hgetall', ckid)
else
     local meta = 'empty'
retrun {ckid, meta}
```

So...how do I do this is lua?

```
     local ckid = redis.pcall('get',KEYS[1])
     if ckid ~= nil then
         local meta = redis.call('hgetall', ckid)
     else
         local meta = 'none'
         local ckid = 'none'
     end

     return {ckid, meta}
```

When using nil..

```
ResponseError: ERR Error running script (call to f_1400713412b0063a26eb0dc063f53a4e3be26380): user_script:12: Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'meta'
```

Comment: Actually redis.call() returns `false` in lua where it returns `nil` in redis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you define a Local variable with in an if statement it only exists for the if statement.  Check out local variable scope in the manual.

Try

```
 local ckid = redis.pcall('get',KEYS[1])
 local meta
 if ckid ~= nil then
     meta = redis.call('hgetall', ckid)
 else
     meta = 'none'
     ckid = 'none'
 end

 return {ckid, meta}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Lua is not my forte and was eager to solve this issue!

Comment: Hmm, I would not use nil. Redis uses false in some cases, for a variety of reason (and depending on versions). Instead of `ckid ~= nil` you should use `if ckid`.

Answer (score 0):

`nil` [It's one of the first things mentioned in the manual.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1)