# What is the value if the key does not exist in eval 'redis.call' in Redis?

Tags: redis, lua

I found how to test variable if `nil` in Lua here [Learn X in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/lua/), equals for `==`, not equals for `~=`, and ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206613/lua-script-and-redis-how-to-test-for-none-value), but why my code does not work like that?

Start Redis server in docker:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin> .\docker.exe run --name redis-work -p 2019:6379 redis
```

Redis client in docker

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin> docker run -it --name redis-cli-work --link redis-work:redis --rm redis redis-cli -h redis -p 6379
```

First:

```
redis:6379> eval 'local r = redis.call("get", "key_which_does_not_exist") return r' 0
(nil)
```

Second:

```
redis:6379> eval 'local r = redis.call("get", "key_which_does_not_exist") if r == nil then return \'nil for key\' else return r end' 0
(nil)
```

Third:

```
redis:6379> eval 'local r = redis.call("get", "key_which_does_not_exist") if r ~= nil then return r else return \'nil for key\' end' 0
(nil)
```

If the key does not exist, I think `redis.call` will return `nil` from the *First* code, but from the second one, I think `r == nil` is false otherwise it will print 'nil for key', does this mean r is not nil?, then from the third one, since r is not nil, why it print `(nil)`, I think only nil result can print `(nil)`.

So the value is, looks like nil in client side, but in the server side, it is neither nil nor not nil, what kind of value is that?

---

The problem is if `key_which_does_not_exist` does not exist, then `r` is false, if `lua` just return this `false` to redis, redis client will turned out to be `(nil)`; for the second code piece, if we want `return r` only if `r == nil` is false, then `r` is false makes `r == nil` false, we return `r` leads to return `false`, redis convert `false` to `(nil)` again; for the last one, `r` is false makes `r ~= nil` true, then lua `return r`, actually return false to redis, redis covert `false` to `(nil)`.

The problem is, in lua, `false` is not `nil`, in redis, `false` from lua will be converted to `(nil)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local r = redis.call('get','foo') if r == false then return 'falsehood' else return r end" 0
"falsehood"
```

Per the docs under ["Conversion between Lua and Redis data types
"](https://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types):

> **Redis to Lua** conversion table.
>   ...
>   * Redis Nil bulk reply and Nil multi bulk reply -> Lua false boolean type

So, when `GET` returns a Redis nil because the key doesn't exist, it is represented as Lua false in this case.

Comment: thanks, to continue, `represented as Lua false in this case.` since false is not nil in lua, then lua return false, but redis convert lua false to nil, hence we have always have nil for such cases,